# Woher kommt „…“ („Punkt Punkt Punkt“)?

Tags: history, typography

Wenn „…“ in einem Satz verwendet wird (meist schriftlich), zeigt es, dass dort noch etwas kommen würde.

1. Woher kommt die Verwendung von drei Punkten und warum sind es drei, nicht zwei vier oder fünf?
2. Was ist der Unterschied zwischen „…“ und „usw.“/„etc.“?

Comment: Darüber haben Linguisten geforscht. Das paper findet man hier (https://www-degruyter-com.uaccess.univie.ac.at/view/j/zfgl.1997.25.issue-1/zfgl.1997.25.1.24/zfgl.1997.25.1.24.xml). Ich werde eine Antwort schreiben, brauche aber etwas Zeit.

Comment: Vor allem würde ich für die verschiedenen Entwicklungsformen gern Bilder finden. Dazu suche ich in den digitalen Heidelberger Manuskripten (http://digi.ub.uni-heidelberg.de/diglit/codheidnf26_1/0001/thumbs). Da es keine Transkription gibt, dauert dies!

Answer (score 9):

Der Dreipunkt ist in der deutschen Orthographie ein eigenständiges Zeichen.

> Bis ins 18. Jahrhundert wurde herumexperimentiert: Es gab drei Punkte in der Diagonale, vier Punkte übers Kreuz, mitunter wurden Sternchen verwendet etc., bevor die drei bis heute verwendeten Punkte herauskamen. Die Funktion war aber die gleiche, sie dienten als Stellvertreter für fehlende Namen oder fehlende Teile in der Sprache, hatten eine Art Formularfunktion. Die Auslassungszeichen standen für etwas Bestimmtes, das später nachgeliefert oder aus Raumgründen weggelassen wurde. Im Grunde waren sie also ökonomische Zeichen. Im späten 18. Jahrhundert entwickelten sie dann ein Eigenleben, sie wurden zu einem Stilmittel, das Gefühle ausdrücken und verstärken sollte. Im Impressionismus wurden die Punkte zu einer richtigen Modeerscheinung, die in der Folge auch Autoren wie Arthur Schnitzler oder Robert Musil häufig verwendeten, sehr zum Leidwesen von Adorno, den das schrecklich gestört hat. [(Quelle)](http://sciencev2.orf.at/stories/1682936/index.html)

Comment: Siehe auch Wikipedia: [Auslassungspunkte](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auslassungspunkte).